# How To Implement Navigation Drawer in windows Phone7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

Hi I'm beginner to this platform, i'm creating one small application what i want to do means on button_Tap navigation drawer should appear which should overlap layoutroot which is Main Grid. Please if any one having the sample code in windows phone 7 development please post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for sliding menu in Windows Phone 7 you can try this solution.

[Sliding menu](https://github.com/Depechie/SettingsPageAnimation/blob/master/SettingsPageAnimation/MainPage.xaml.cs)..

[Sliding Menu Example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27557.windows-phone-control-animation-while-navigating-between-panes-inside-a-windows-phone-page.aspx)

This is good example for sliding menu.

Comment: hi vijay i dont want to push the mainlayout i want sample like android settings menu

Comment: I don't know there is nav drawer for wp7. I have found a sample for my application from here. [Try this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb386b/implementing-navigation-drawer-for-windows-phone-8-1/). But don't know it will support for WP7.

Comment: ok anyway thanks for your support vijay.One more thing do you have any idea how to upload images using propfind method in windows phone7